# Nesting categories for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

API returns the categories like so:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 14308
            [parent_id] => 14308
            [level] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 179836
            [parent_id] => 14308
            [level] => 1
        )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 230022
                [parent_id] => 179836
                [level] => 2
            )
```

And I need to insert them in the DB like so:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╗
║ category_id ║ parent_id ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╣
║       14308 ║         0 ║
║      179836 ║     14308 ║
║      230022 ║    179836 ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╝
```

... which is easy, but the `category_to_path` table is tricky which I can't seem to figure out. It needs to be like this:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ category_id ║ path_id ║ level ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║       14308 ║   14308 ║     0 ║
║      179836 ║   14308 ║     0 ║
║      179836 ║  179836 ║     1 ║
║      230022 ║   14308 ║     0 ║
║      230022 ║  179836 ║     1 ║
║      230022 ║  230022 ║     2 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$path_ids;
for ($i=0; $i <= ($category->CategoryLevel-1); $i++) { 
// -1 cause the API returns a non zero-based level

  $path_ids[$i]['category_id'] = $category->CategoryID;

  if ($category->CategoryLevel-1 == $i) {
    $path_ids[$i]['path_id'] = $category->CategoryParentID[0];
  }
  elseif ($category->CategoryLevel-1) {
    // ?
  }

  $path_ids[$i]['level'] = $i;

}
```

Comment: In general this might require a recursive query to find all the paths.

Comment: Do you know how many levels deep is the deepest path in the table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 3 max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to rewrite array after obtaining it from the API so it can looks this:

```
[14308] => Array
(
    [parent_id] => 14308
    [level] => 0
)

[179836] => Array
(
    [parent_id] => 14308
    [level] => 1
)

[230022] => Array
(
    [parent_id] => 179836
    [level] => 2
)
```

When you get your array from the API you can process it with simple foreach loop.

```
$arrayFromApi = apiCallToObtainData();    
$newArray = [];
foreach($arrayFromApi as $value){
    $newArray[$value['category_id']] = [
        $value['parent_id'], 
        $value=['level'],
    ];
}
```

Now you can easily access parents so it shouldn't be difficult to achieve what you need.

Comment: Rewriting the API is not an option.

Comment: I don't mean rewriting API - you can rewrite array after obtaining it from API.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should give you the categories and paths.  It does not give the levels, since your original data lacks any sort of row number.  You might need to use some dynamic SQL if you want to get the levels.

The strategy I used is to cross join the categories, which generates all possible starting and ending points.  It also generates some paths not supported by the table.  To remove these unwanted paths, I check each path against a subquery to make sure that it could be created by traversing from category to path in 3 steps or less.

```
SELECT t1.category_id AS category_id,
       t2.category_id AS path_id
FROM yourTable t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable t2
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.category_id AS category_id_1,
           t2.category_id AS category_id_2,
           t3.category_id AS category_id_3
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.parent_id = t2.category_id
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t3
        ON t2.parent_id = t3.category_id
) t2
    ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id_1 AND
       t2.category_id IN (t2.category_id_1, t2.category_id_2, t2.category_id_3)
ORDER BY category_id,
         path_id
```

Comment: The PHP code in the description is what I get from the API which I then store in an array to write to DB all at once, but I haven't been able to insert the rows programatically yet, thats the issue.

Comment: So are you saying you already have the `category_to_path` table generated?

Comment: Yes, its the OpenCart ecommerce software. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162193/opencart-how-to-accurately-populate-oc-category-path so the tables exist, i just need to populate them with the data from API

Comment: I can't downvote your question now, but would, since it has nothing directly to do with MySQL yet you labelled it as such.

Comment: It has everything to do with MySQL since I need to create a loop (or a recursive function) in a way that it inserts the data into the tables correctly. Maybe you misunderstood, or I wasn't too clear.

Comment: Fetch category list from API, insert categories in the category table, store paths in the path table <- the tricky part.

Comment: `It has everything to do with MySQL` ... but you're not looking for a solution _in_ MySQL, right?  Nothing wrong with a PHP question, but your wording implied that you want a query to generate `category_to_path`.  But you don't want this.

Comment: Yes, not `in` MySQL, thats why I've used `for`