# Dynamic Drop Down for categories based on parent_id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

My query is related to Dynamic Drop Down  option in PHP which you think might be an existing question asked before but my scenario is a bit typical as all the values for drop downs will be fetched from the **same table**

Requirements -

> 1. Drop will be based on INNER JOIN of two tables, **oc_category** and **oc_category_description** (to be used for displaying category name in option field of dropdown)

Common field between the two tables **`category_id`**

Fields to be used

**oc_category** -> `category_id` , `parent_id`

**oc_category_description** -> `name`

For Understanding the ***STRUCTURE*** of `oc_category`

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773602/6792962) to understand the structure of **`oc_category`** table

So in my case, there are 3 levels of categories - **PRIMARY(Level 1) , SECONDARY(Level 2) & TERTIARY(Level 3)**

For Example - `Consumer Electronics` (PRIMARY) > `Mobile Phones`(SECONDARY) > `iPhone`(TERTIARY)

Now I want a 3 drop downs -

Drop Down 1 -> PRIMARY CATEGORIES having **`parent_id`** **'0'**
Value of the Drop Down option should **category_id** and value displayed should be **name**

My Current `mysql` query for 1st Drop Down is -

```
SELECT cat.category_id, cat.parent_id, catd.name FROM oc_category AS cat INNER JOIN oc_category_description AS catd ON cat.category_id=catd.category_id
```

I have **15** PRIMARY CATEGORIES , so I thought of using **WHERE cat.category_id<16** in the above query.

Drop Down 2 -> SECONDARY CATEGORIES having **`parent_id`** relating to **PRIMARY CATEGORY** in `oc_category` table.

So once I select PRIMARY CATEGORY, *Drop Down 2* will load all **SECONDARY CATEGORIES** categories linked to its parent CATEGORY.

Drop Down 3 -> TERTIARY CATEGORIES having **`parent_id`** relating to **SECONDARY CATEGORY** in `oc_category` table.

So once I select SECONDARY CATEGORY, *Drop Down 3* will load all **TERTIARY CATEGORIES** categories linked to its parent CATEGORY.

I would prefer using AJAX here.

FYI - *There are 2339 categories in which there are **15 PRIMARY CATEGORIES**, **367 SECONDARY CATEGORIES** & **1957 TERTIARY CATEGORIES***

Sincere thanks to all developers in advance , who've considered answering my questions and giving there valuable time.

Comment: Really where you are stuck while implementing this section? Building the query, table?or making ajax call? or change events with the drop down? or all of them?

Comment: Making the AJAX call and the query, to be precise

Comment: my page name is Category.php

Could you try with a dummy on your WAMP (if using, or elsewhere) with a database as prescribed ?

Because, your Dummy Dropdowns work, but the real ones don't!

I've commented out the dummy and uncommented the real ones, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  //var items = populateDropdowns(0);
  var items = dummyPopulateDropdowns(0, 'primary');
  $('#drp_primary').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('#drp_primary').append($('<option value="' + items[i].category_id + '">' + items[i].name + ' </option>'));
  }
});
$(document).on('change', '#drp_primary', function() {
  var mainCategory = $(this).val();
  //var items = populateDropdowns(mainCategory);
  var items = dummyPopulateDropdowns(mainCategory, 'secondary');
  $('#drp_secondary').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('#drp_secondary').append($('<option value="' + items[i].category_id + '">' + items[i].name + ' </option>'));
  }
});
$(document).on('change', '#drp_secondary', function() {
  var secondaryCategory = $(this).val();
  //var items = populateDropdowns(secondaryCategory);
  var items = dummyPopulateDropdowns(secondaryCategory, 'tertiory');
  $('#drp_tertiory').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $('#drp_tertiory').append($('<option value="' + items[i].category_id + '">' + items[i].name + ' </option>'));
  }
});

function populateDropdowns(parentID) {
  var items = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: "your url with",
    data: {
      mainCategoryID: parentID
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
      items = result;

    }
  });
  return items;
}

function dummyPopulateDropdowns(parentID, drpdwn) {
  var items = [];
  if (drpdwn == 'primary') {
    items.push({
      category_id: 0,
      name: 'Baby Products'
    }, {
      category_id: 1,
      name: 'Consumer Electronics'
    });
  } else if (drpdwn == 'secondary') {
    items.push({
      category_id: 10,
      name: 'Land Phones'
    }, {
      category_id: 11,
      name: 'Mobile Phones'
    });
  } else if (drpdwn == 'tertiory') {
    items.push({
      category_id: 100,
      name: 'Iphone'
    }, {
      category_id: 101,
      name: 'Blackbery'
    });
  }
  return items;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='drp_primary'>
</select>
<br />
<select id='drp_secondary'>
</select>
<br />
<select id='drp_tertiory'>
</select>
```

this part explains how you can handle the drop down and ajax calls.
here make sure to comment line '*dummyPopulateDropdowns*(0, 'primary');' and uncomment '*populateDropdowns*' so that you can make the real ajax call, replacing your url.

primary - QUERY

```
SELECT cat.category_id, cat.parent_id, catd.name 
FROM oc_category AS cat 
INNER JOIN oc_category_description AS catd 
   ON cat.category_id = catd.category_id
WHERE parent_id = 0
```

secondary and tertiory - QUERY

```
SELECT cat.category_id, cat.parent_id, catd.name 
FROM oc_category AS cat 
INNER JOIN oc_category_description AS catd 
   ON cat.category_id = catd.category_id
WHERE parent_id = <SELECTED CATEGORY ID>
```

I am not good at writing php codes, hope someone else in this community will help you to modify this to make this work for you.

Note the method *dummyPopulateDropdowns* is just for filling the dropdown with rough data.

Comment: url : "your url with", what is this to be substituted with?

Comment: like 'http://localhost:1989/Items/GetCategory' with argument mainCategoryID. i am not sure whether you are running you application from localhost or not. So substitute suitably.

Comment: `SELECT cat.category_id, cat.parent_id, catd.name 
FROM oc_category AS cat 
INNER JOIN oc_category_description AS catd 
   ON cat.category_id = catd.category_id
WHERE parent_id = <SELECTED CATEGORY ID>`

What is to be replaced with <SELECTED CATEGORY ID> here ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise as to what should I name these queries and should I use a **`IF`** & **`WHILE`** statement with `mysqli_fetch_array`

Also, how are these queries linking to the AJAX function?